# Box shape with right angled trapezoids

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm wondering if this shape can be done in css3 with as little html as possible:

[image: Screenshot]

So far, I've managed to do this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: -1px;
}
.box:after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r9uehvvt/), but I don't know how to skew it like that so that I have right angled trapezoid on top and bottom.

Comment: Basically what I need are `:before` and `:after` elements that are right angled trapezoids. Then I can just place them on top and bottom of the box (the after one is just rotated before by 180 degrees)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The shape needs no extra elements

The shape can be created with just the `<div>`:

- The left side is created with the divs left, top and bottom borders.
- The right side is made by `:before` and its top, right and bottom borders
- The spans joining the two boxes are created with the `:after` thanks to `skewY`

[Note the browser support of the transform property.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) IE 9 requires the `-ms-` prefix, and Safari and the Android browser require `-webkit-`.

[image: Screenshot]

### Working Example - just the shape

The CSS has been condensed and the border style of the pseudo elements is inherited from the div itself.

```css
div {
  border: solid 4px #000;
  border-right-width: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: inherit;
  border-right-width: 4px;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 13px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div:after {
  width: 20px;
  border-right: none;
  top: 5px;
  transform: skewY(40deg);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Working example - with text

With the example above, the contents will not be contained inside the entire shape. Rather, it will be constrained inside the divs half width. The contents needs to be wrapped in a `<span>` with 200% width to punch it outside of the divs constraints.

```css
div {
  border: solid 4px #000;
  border-right-width: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: inherit;
  border-right-width: 4px;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 13px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div:after {
  width: 20px;
  border-right: none;
  top: 5px;
  transform: skewY(40deg);
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  width: 200%;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This is me writing a large amount of words into the div. I think that you may want a span in order to contain them.</span></div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the one with the least amount of elements, and I can write inside of it, put icons etc. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! I said in comments under the post, that what would be ideal solution is to create right angled trapezoid for `:before` and `:after` elements, and then just overlay them over the box, but I can't seem to find how to create right angled trapezoid out of one element :\

Comment: @dingo_d - I added a second example with text. The span is needed to wrap the contents of the shape so that it will not be constrained by the divs width (which is only half of the shape)

Comment: I agree :) Great and detailed.

Comment: @misterManSam: Off-topic comment but we have created a chat room for css-shapes tag [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/lets-get-shaped). Please feel free to join in when you find time mate :)

Answer (score 4):

Using two different elements:

1) Separate the shape in two different rectangular

2)After use pseudo-elements `after` and `before` to create the connection line.

My approach:

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-right: 0;
}
.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 112px;
  left: 164px;
  border-left: 0;
}
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  right: -15px;
  top: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: Looks great, but I'd need to be able to write inside the box, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've used four `div`s: `.left`, `.right`, `.middle-top` and `.middle-bottom`; and skewed `.middle-top` and `.middle-bottom` to add those connection lines.

```css
.left {
    width: 40px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}
.right {
    width: 40px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 160px;
}
.middle-top {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    transform: matrix(1, 0.5, -0.5, 1, 0, 0);
    top: 55px;
    left: 137px;
    z-index: 9;
}
.middle-bottom {
    width: 21px;
    height: 20px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    transform: matrix(1, 0.5, -0.5, 1, 0, 0);
    top: 158px;
    left: 135px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="middle-top"></div>
<div class="middle-bottom"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Works, but I've already got my answer, I'll give you upvote for effort :)